# Drupal 7 upgrade to Drupal 8 upgrade UI fails to connect to localhost database while using docker for windows

Tags: docker, drupal, upgrade, migrate

I have Docker on Win 10 pro integrated with linux subsystem for windows (using Debian)
- Docker is configured to Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS so everything plays nice locally...

I have 2 docker-compose "setups/stacks" running:

1. PHP container running Drupal 7 with a mysql container and a phpmyadmin container running.
2. PHP container running Drupal 8 with a mysql container and a phpmyadmin container running.

The Drupal 7 site is a backup of a production site and is running locally just fine.

The Drupal 8 site is installed and prepped for upgrade and migration and is running locally without any problems as well.

I can start and stop containers at will and reach the sites via localhost with port assignments provided by my compose.yml as follows:

- Drupal 7 at localhost:9191
- Drupal 8 at localhost:8585

Each site connects to it's database properly, as well I can access PMA by a specified port like I do the actual sites and it interacts with the database(s) properly.

HOWEVER I cannot get Drupal 8 upgrade to connect to my localhost Drupal 7 database NO matter what I try! It just won't connect and gives some error depending on what I've tried. I even tried to connect to the production site db and still nothing...

So I obviously have something wrong!

The basic database info provided to each drupal site is similar to the following:

- database: databasename
- user: databaseusername
- password: databasepassword
- host: hostname
- port: 3306
- driver: mysql

In Drupal 8 on /upgrade/credentials page for "Database host" I've tried:

- localhost
- localhost:3306
- localhost:8989 (which is the PMA port used to access PMA via web
  browser locally)
- hostname (set by docker-compose.yml while building the PMA container,
  the PMA_HOST: variable under environment which I have to use for the
  database credentials in settings.php for drupal for it to work with
  my docker setup properly)
- 127.0.0.1
- localhost:hostname
- IPv4 of local docker network (172.XX.XXX.XXX)

And all I get is SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Cannot assign requested address or SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

when using localhost I get: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

I also copied and pasted from the drupal 7 settings.php database credentials to the Drupal 8 upgrade page to be sure I'm not producing an error with any typos.

I am also not getting any error logs in drupal 8 recent log messages page (which is active) just in the upgrade page itself when trying to connect to the drupal 7 database.

I've been at this for hours trying to find a solution with no avail and my stress level is beyond frustrated as I feel this should be simple (at least this stage of the process)

The drupal 8 install is at the latest current version 8.6.15, Apache Debian 2.4.25, PHP 7.2.17

The drupal 7 install is at version 7.65, Apache Debian 2.4.25, PHP 7.1.27

Just to recap both sites work beautifully on there own locally setup as they are, I just can't get Drupal 8 upgrade to connect to drupal 7 database.

This has to be something simple or maybe I need to take another approach, I just don't know having been at this for hours and hours already.

I do have drush and composer active in the PHP containers for each site as well and in the drupal 8 site I've added the drush migrate/upgrade tools/modules and activated them as well (and yes I have installed the latest ones to work with the latest version of drupal)

I've been through all the guides and just about every resource I can find on migrate/upgrade from drupal 7 to 8 and I can't find anything on trouble shooting this..

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as my only other thoughts are there is a problem with the core UI upgrade module itself or is conflicting with something else.

UPDATE: Same problem with live active domains when trying to do the same thing?
- Does not appear to be Docker, Windows or Debian Problems what so ever!
- Just doesn't work!

Guess I need to open an issue at drupal.org

Comment: Hi, how did you solve this issue? I'm experiencing the same, not only on my Windows 10 laptop but also on a debian server.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Lido, I never actually solved the issue - and never even got a response on drupal.org (as I'm still under the impression this should be doable where each site is installed at different locations) ...HOWEVER - I did manage to find a way to make it work!

Comment: Install both sites under one domain (if live same stack or docker container) or if local (recommend) using say docker or another stack to same IP and port - same for DB's ..if docker put both in one container or install both sites to the same DB (recommend 1 DB per site running in say a single MySQL container) this way the sites a D7 and a D8/9 are running under the same network as well as the DB's. Hope that helps!    ~sidgrafix

Comment: To clarify, if your using docker 1 MySQL container with 2 DB's and 1 Debian container with 2 sites installed (obviously something D7 site under say /var/www/html/web and D8/9 to /var/www/html/web/upgrade) ..whatever path structure you use www-data needs to have access to both installs (make sure to set path for in settings.php at least for the D8/9 and let the D7 default unless you use other custom paths set those)

Comment: Hi sidgrafix, thanks for the update! It turns out the DB connection was stored in the D8 database, and the connection details were not up-to-date (I changed the docker stack but was still using the previous database). Strange that it is stored in the DB and it's not using the one from settings.php

Comment: Hi Lido, off the top of my head (as it's been quite some time since I've done anything w/migration) I believe in your D8 database the D7 database settings/credentials should exist as they are input thru the migration modules - so that should be correct "seeing what your seeing." Again I'm not 100% on that... it's been awhile! The only thing I remember having to set in the settings.php (aside from the D8 DB credentials) was the private files path for the D7 install once I was able to connect.. If you have a couple days I can put together a quick basic guide recreating what I did to make it work